# Ring theory question: $I=\langle x,2 \rangle$ prime/maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ , let $I = \lbrace f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] : f (0) \text{ is an even integer} \rbrace.$

1. Is $I=\langle x,2 \rangle$ a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?
2. Is $I=\langle x,2 \rangle$ a maximal ideal?

Comment: Anything you tried?

Comment: That doesn't show that $I$ is maximal, it only shows that $\langle x \rangle$ isn't. What if $\langle x, 2, 3x^2 \rangle \supset \langle x, 2 \rangle$? (it isn't, but who says there doesn't exist some larger ideal)

Comment: Do you know these theorems? $I$ is maximal iff $R/I$ is a field, and $I$ is prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain. I assume this is the way to go if you're allowed to use those.

Comment: This question looks like an easy problem from Gallian, although I'm sure it's many other places. I think he may not have those theorems yet, and may not have knowledge of PIDs. It's probably best to just check these from definitions, which is relatively simple.

Comment: Oh, looks like he does have those theorems, then.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x, 2 \rangle$? Try finding representatives in each coset. For example, $x^3 - 2x^2 + 5x - 1 \equiv x(x^2 - 2x + 5) - 1 \equiv -1$. You'll find that it's isomorphic to a very manageable ring.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem, but without the OP specifying what theorems he already knows/understands, it is near impossible to give an answer at the appropriate level. So, @user114873, please provide some context for this problem: what do you already know, what have you covered, and what are your own thoughts?

Comment: BTW when you look on related questions (on the right) you can see there this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238374/langle-x-2-rangle-is-a-maximal-ideal-in-mathbbzx

Answer (score 7):

You can really solve this without using any higher principles.  Here is an elementary solution:

Well, what IS $I$? It is an ideal that consists of integer polynomials that have even constant term.  $f = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $f\in I$ exactly means that $a_0$ is even.

Okay, $I$ is prime: we need show $f,g\notin I \implies fg\notin I$.  Well, if $f$ and $g$ both have a constant term that is not even (i.e. odd), can their product have a constant term that is even?  No.

$I$ is maximal: we show that if we pick any element not in $I$, say $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x] - I$, then $I + (f) = \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Well, $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x] - I$ means that $f = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $a_0$ odd.  This means that $1\in I+(f)$ (why?), and hence we can't make $I$ any bigger without making it become the whole ring.  Hence, $I$ is maximal.

Comment: This is nice, yet the OP must be clear that the second part (the maximal thing) may be a little trickier to prove than the first one...+1

Answer (score 4):

You can go the abstract way directly using the first isomorphism theorems:

$$\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x,2\rangle\cong\left(\Bbb Z[x]/\langle 2\rangle\right)/\left(\langle x,2\rangle/\langle2\rangle\right)\cong\Bbb F_2[x]/\langle x\rangle\cong\Bbb F_2$$

With $\;\Bbb F_2\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=\;$ the field with two elements.

Now just use the already mentioned theorem: a proper ideal in a commutative unitary ring is maximal iff its quotient with the ring is a field.

Answer (score 2):

By the description in the first line of the question, $I$ is the kernel of a ring homomorphism $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z[X]\to\Z/2\Z$ that maps $P\mapsto P(0)\bmod 2$. Since $\Z/2\Z$ is a field and the homomorphism surjective, $I$ is a maximal and hence prime ideal. (For maximal: any proper ideal containing $I$ is the inverse image of a proper ideal of $\Z/2\Z$, hence of $\{0\}$; for being a prime ideal, being the kernel of any morphism to an integral domain would have sufficed.)